# Сhanging the addresses of variables depending on their initialization location

Tags: c

I read the book "Hacking: the Art of the Exploit", and there was an example in which, when initializing the int auth_flag variable before the char array buffer_password[16], auth_flag is located at an address older than buffer_password. And if you initialize auth_flag after buffer_password, then it will be located at an address lower than buffer_password. But for some reason, the address of the auth_flag variable remains the same in two cases. Can you tell me what's the matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_authentication(char *password) {
    char buffer_password[16];
    int auth_flag = 0;
    
    strcpy(buffer_password, password);
    
    if (strcmp(buffer_password, "brilling") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
    if (strcmp(buffer_password, "outgrabe") == 0)
        auth_flag = 1;
        
    return auth_flag;
}
```

I tried initializing the variable both after the array and before, but the address remained the same.

Comment: What does looking at the generated assembly tell you?

Comment: Even for an old compiler, there is no particular reason why initializing a variable would change its position in memory. It's just that the author found a compiler that did that. An optimizing compiler might not store `auth_flag` in memory at all if it has a spare register.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Re “there is no particular reason why initializing a variable would change its position in memory”: Grouping all objects initialized to zero could enable optimized initialization.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between where a variable is initialized and where it is allocated. The order of declaration and initialization in the C source is completely irrelevant in regards of the memory layout.

Compiling your code in a modern compiler (gcc x86_64 -O3 for Linux), then `auth_flag` is not allocated *at all* - it is placed in a CPU register.

All of the above held very true when your book was first published in 2003 and is still the case today. Therefore the example from the book sounds like nonsense even by year 2003 standards. Notably, then and now, programs aren't released with optimizations disabled, nor are they released together with the full C source for the hacker's convenience.

Answer (score 0):

> ... The problem with modern C compiler is that compiler is smarter than you. Old compilers in the 70's or early 80's blindly followed the source as closely as possible. Modern optimizing compilers are only required to have the same observable behaviour as what a naive translation would do. They are allowed to reorganize variables and/or blocks of code provided the output of the program is not changed. And the address of a variable does not belong to the observable behaviour...

–
Serge Ballesta

Comment: And one more question. As I understand it, there will be many points in this book that I will not be able to do on a modern compiler. Can you tell me how to access the old one?

Comment: Try looking at the beginning of the book - maybe they wrote what they used. A pretty good guess would be gcc of an appropriate version (look at the book's publishing year). Or any old compiler.

Comment: @anatolyg The problem isn't the book's age, the statements from the question didn't make sense back in year 2003 either, when the first edition was published.